# generate a path to go backward a given path

Tags: shell, cd

Assuming I have the following relative path:

```
MY_PATH := first/second/third
```

I am searching for a preferably short shell command to achieve the following:

```
MY_NEW_PATH := ../../..
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ MY_PATH=first/second/third
$ sed -e 's#[^/]\+/\?#../#g' <<<"$MY_PATH"
../../../
```

The easiest way to get that path without the trailing slash is just to remove it.

```
$ MY_PATH=first/second/third
$ cdup=$(sed -e 's#[^/]\+/\?#../#g' <<<"$MY_PATH")
$ echo "$cdup"
../../../
$ echo "${cdup%/}"
../../..
```

You could also use something like this (which generates an uglier, but still valid, path):

```
$ MY_PATH=first/second/third
$ sed -e 's#[^/]\+/\?#./.#g' <<<"$MY_PATH"
./../../.
```

There might be a better alternative to get a trailing-slash-less path but I'd have to think about it more.

Comment: And how to achieve without the last "/"`?

Comment: @nilo I'd have to think about it a bit more and play with it some but a first version that does that is now added to the answer.